# Is there any way to help with the sniper rifle kickback?

Tags: rage

In RAGE, is there an add-on of sorts for the sniper rifle to help with the crazy kickback when the gun is shot while fully zoomed? If so, can it be built or purchased somewhere? I noticed other add-ons for the shotgun, and the sniper rifle does get a loading mod.

I was able to luck my way through the first Job Board sniper mission in Wellspring, but am having trouble getting through the next one with the caravan.

Comment: The only thing mentioned so far in the _RAGE_ wiki page for the [Sniper Rifle](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_Rifle) is the semi-auto upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finished the game (not at the 100% achievement level) and the only Sniper Rifle modification I've seen is the semi-auto.

The [*RAGE* Wikia](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_Rifle) says that the only modification is the semi-auto upgrade.